# Arduino declaring a unsigned byte array

Tags: c++, arrays

With refer to [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900090/sum-calculation-error-in-arduino-mega-2560)

I solve the issue by following only part of the solution (steps 2 - 4). Everything worked fine and today the checksum failed again(message not verified by server).

So I guess that I did not declared the unsigned byte array (as in step 1), and cause Arduino to randomly pick to use signed/unsigned byte array.

However, declaring unsigned byte array like this

> unsigned byte MSGpack[187] = {
>     0x00                            };

prompts error in Arduino, stating

> error: 'MSGpack' was not declared in this scope
>
> In function 'void injectByte(float, int)':
>
> error: 'MSGpack' was not declared in this scope

How should I declare a unsigned byte array in Arduino? Thanks!

Comment: `MSGpack` must be _visible_ wherever you are using it. If it's defined in another translation unit you will need to provide an `extern` declaration so the compiler knows it exists. if it's in a namespace you will likely need to provide a fully qualified name (i.e. namespacename::MSGpack`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `uint8_t`:

```
uint8_t MSGpack[187] = {0};
```